# Tracking customer portal using google analytics

Tags: customer-portal, google-apps

I have customer portal enabled on my org. I want to add google analytics to it.  Is this possible? If yes, How can i do this?

Comment: does your portal use the standard pages or visualforce pages ?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible.

Your customer portal works as any other site for Google analytics.

You only have to add the javascript snippet that Google Analytics gives you when you are configuring your account.

It is always a good idea to put this code on a `component` to include into all your site pages. Also you could use `templates` to add it to all pages at once.

sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

[More information](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking)